# Is it possible to concisely tell SQL SELECT to omit some temporary/dummy columns?

Tags: sql, refactoring, dummy-variable

Suppose I have this query:

```sql
select 
  x + y as _total,
  abs(x - y) / _total as _err,
  round(100 * _err) as pct_err,
  x,
  y
from foo;
```

This assumes I have a table with `x` and `y`, and calculates an error between them. Note that columns I prefixed with `_` are dummy columns - they're only there to show the steps of the calculation more clearly. Is there a way to omit them from the result?

- I don't want to simply collapse the three columns into a single expression. It would be messier, and consider also a calculation with 10 steps and much longer field names.
- I don't want to make this a CTE and then re-select only the columns I want. That seems too much hassle for such a simple thing.
- It would be okay if I could just put the dummy columns at the end where they would be out of the way, but SQL doesn't seem to allow referencing a column that comes after.

Note that "no" is an acceptable answer, if you have reasonably comprehensive knowledge of SQL syntax :)

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: @jarlh How about posting that answer as an answer, rather than a comment? :)